# Number of cards picked (with replacement) until a full set of cards appears?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ is a random variable defined as the number of cards chosen from a pack of $n$ cards (with replacement) until a full set of cards appears. So for example
if I begin picking cards I might get lucky and pick $n$ distinct cards, in which case I took $n$ cards to get a full set. Or I might be less lucky and take
$n+54$ cards until I get the full set of $n$ distinct cards. My question then is:

---

***My question***

What is the probability mass function related to $X$? Or in other words, what's 
the probability that I get the full set of $n$ distinct cards after $k$ tries?

---

***My attempt***

My attempt was the following:
Best case scenario we get $n$ distinct cards after $n$ cards chosen. 
Then the probability would be $\frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{n} ... \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{n} = (\frac{1}{n})^n$.

Or, and this is were I get iffy,  we could get $n$ distinct cards after $n+1$ cards chosen. In that case I would still have to chose $n$ distinct cards $\frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{n} ... \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{n}$, but I would have one repeated (doesn't matter
which one so long that it is not the last, so I would have
$(\frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{n} ... \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{n}) (\frac{n-1}{n})$

Following the pattern, for $m \in \mathbb{N}$ I have that my probability mass function  for the
random variable Y is

$P(Y=n+m) = (\frac{1}{n})^n(\frac{n-1}{n})^m$

Is this wrong?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: The probability of the best case scenario is not right. There are $n^n$ equally likely sequences of $n$ cards. Of these, $n!$ have all the cards distinct, for a probability of $\frac{n!}{n^n}$.

Comment: This question is known as the coupon collector's problem.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem .

Comment: Your "best case scenario" calculated the probability of getting all $n$ cards in the first $n$ tries *in a specified order*. Since there are $n!$ possible orders, that explains why you were off by a factor $n!$ from the correct answer in the comment from @AndréNicolas .